# Xamarin Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding

I genuinely can't work out if I'm being an idiot or not, what I'm to do is so simple!

I have a ViewModel with a public Username field.

Originally I tried to get the Entry to display an initial value but upon looking further I've discovered I can't even get the view to update the viewmodel.

I want the text to reflect the entered username when I click the button and display it in the Alert.

My ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

My Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage Padding="15,15,15,15" 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
x:Class="EngineerApp.LoginPage">
<AbsoluteLayout>
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
    <Image Source="traklogo.png" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>
    <Label TextColor="#207cad" Text="Username" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Username}"></Label>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Black" Placeholder="Please enter your username..." x:Name="txtUsername" />
</StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My Page's Code:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{

    public LoginViewModel viewModel = new LoginViewModel();

    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;

        btnLogIn.Clicked += delegate
        {
            DisplayAlert("Test",viewModel.Username,"Okay");
            return;

        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Ordinaily `OnPropertyChanged` would be called in the setters.

Comment: Hi sorry I actually removed it because I didn't think it was required. Updated accordingly.

Comment: That binding on the `Label` right before the `Entry` hints that you do need it. Databinding needs `INotifyPropertyChanged` to drive the magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out. The page BEFORE this page was passing in it's own BindingContext. Removing this resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

This working snippet from a LoginViewModel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` is in an app published in stores:

```
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set
        {
            if (username == value) return;
            username = value?.ToLowerInvariant();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And the associated `Entry` XAML snippet:

```
          <Entry x:Name="UsernameEntry" HeightRequest="45" Keyboard="Email"
                Placeholder="{Binding LabelUsername}" Text="{Binding Username}">
```

Comment: Why do I need to implement the interface? Xamarin does data binding by default doesn't it?

Comment: no, INPC is the mechanism the Binding functions rely on to know that changes have been made to the model/viewmodel.  Without it the UI would never know when to update itself.

Comment: I'm not trying to update the UI, I'm trying to read from the View Model.

Comment: if you only care about that, try OneWayToSource instead of TwoWay

Comment: however, if you don't use INPC your Label will never get updated

Comment: I just want one way binding to work for now. I can't even get that to work. 

It works if I set the BindingContext = new ViewModel() then evaltuate the BindingContext on the button click, but not if I define the ViewModel first and set that as the BindingContext, then try to evaluate the ViewModel afterwards.

Comment: OneWay means the UI is updated to match the Model.  You would need to set the value of the property when you create the Model to test that.